# How to link drop-down menu to table using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

**I am trying to populate a html table based on the selection from drop-down menu**. i.e. when I selected an option from drop-down menu, it shows a table having description of that selected item fetched from the database like it fetches a row of that value and shows it in a table.

Now for this, I have to use Ajax & Jquery but i don't know much about ajax.

Can you please help me this?

Here is my code:

```js
$("#courses").change(function(){
  var course = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
     url:'your php page url',
    type:'post',
    data:'course='+course,
    success:function(response){
    // your drop down box is in response
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="courses" id="courses" class="dropdownclass" ><option selected="selected" value="" disabled selected hidden >-- Select an option --</option>

<?php  
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db');

$sql = "SELECT courses FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
}

?>

</select>
```

I don't know what to add in ajax and where to put the table and link it with drop-down menu. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: To understand how Ajax works : 1/ From the FRONT, you get the value you want send to your PHP - 2/ Then you send this value using Ajax with `url : 'your_script php'` and `data : {'key' : your_value}` - 3/ From the BACK, in `your_script.php` you get this value : `$value = $_POST['key']` (if you send your Ajax value with `type : 'post'`), then you use this `$value` to get the data you want, then you it back to your Ajax call `echo $the_result_you_want;` - 4/ In your Ajax call in the success part, you use this result to add the option in your select

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample static code to implement your functionality. You can add your dynamic content using sql and php.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="paragraph-div">
        <select id="courses">
            <option value="cource_1">Cource 1</option>
            <option value="cource_2">Cource 2</option>
            <option value="cource_3">Cource 3</option>
            <option value="cource_4">Cource 4</option>
        </select>
        <table id="myTable" border="1">

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#courses").change(function(){
    var course = $(this).val();
    $.post('data.php', {course: course}, function(response){
        // your drop down box is in response
        $("#myTable").html(response);
    });
});

</script>
```

data.php

```
<?php

    $course = $_POST['course'];

    // Fetch data from db related to $course

    $html = '<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Course Name : </td>
            <td>Course 1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Course Description : </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>';

    echo $html;
    die();
?>
```

Hope now it's clear.

Comment: where do i add the html table?

Comment: Check snippet updated. You get data using ajax append just in dom

Comment: Or else you just append values from ajax result to dom

Comment: In url, I set index.php on which my table is and the same code as you suggested by but when i run it, It shows the table column name without selecting drop-down value and when I select the value it simply shows that selected value

Comment: In index.php I have added this drop-down code which I have posted and  table is also on that page

Comment: Ajax url should be different than current means your dropdown file and table file both different. Put js code in dropdown file.

Comment: Still no result. Now it isn't even showing the table columns as I created a new page for table

Comment: I think it's working now. But I want to store the selected value of drop down so that i fetch the row of that selected drop-down and show in the table on other page. Can u please help me with this

Comment: Check i updated code with static content. Now you can find result